# Colorbox popup not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, gallery, colorbox

I am trying to insert a popup window that opens by clicking caption text in Jalbum(It is a software that make html galleries). I downloaded the files to make the colorbox popup from this website http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-window.phtml and copied that required code into this web page http://www.tellmefilms.tk/indejx.html. The code is

var images=new Array(
    {file:'slides/1.jpg',video:false,thumb:'thumbs/1.jpg',caption:'

Some text',thmcapt:'1 ',link:'',date:'',mod:15395,size:'42 kB',width:264,height:520,rel:0},

Here as you can see the id link_content is given to  tag but still clicking the Text does not open the popup. Please help me in solving this problem and if color box popup is not possible please suggest another popup just like the colorbox popup.

Comment: I hope you got colorbox from the author's site (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) and not from blogspam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery.colorbox-min.js file is 404ing. `<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` That file does not exist. Make sure it's uploaded on your server.

Comment: Sorry I have uploaded the files now.